# Servicestack - UNAUTHORIZED after successful login

Tags: servicestack

I must have missed something, but I get Unauthorized errors for operations that are annotated with `[Authorize]` AFTER a successful login. I tried the annotation on several levels: The service class, RequestDTOs and also single methods of my service class. Behaviour is always the same.

I have created my own AuthProvider derived from `CredentialsAuthProvider`. I do NOT use OrmLite, I use NHibernate 4. My client is a WPF application. My AppHost.Configure() method looks as follows:

```
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        //Config examples
        //this.Plugins.Add(new PostmanFeature());
        //this.Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new BediCredentialsAuthProvider(), 
            }
        ));
        Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
        container.RegisterValidators(typeof(AppUserValidator).Assembly);
        container.RegisterAs<BediAuthEvents, IAuthEvents>();
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
    }
```

And then I notice some other strange (to me) behaviour: I implemented custom AuthEvents for `OnAuthenticated()`and `OnLogout`. I write a log entry in both cases. I use the property `session.UserAuthName` in both events. In `OnAuthenticated()` this property is filled correctly. After a call to an operation where I got an unauthorized error the `OnLogout` method cannot reference the `session.UserAuthName` property, because it is **null**.

Any idea, what is going wrong here? Something seems to be wrong with my sessions but I have no idea what!

**Message Update**

Sorry, I mistyped my annotation. I am using **`[Authenticate]`** and **not** `[Authorize]`! Here is a sample from inside my service class:

```
[Authenticate]
public object Post(CreateAppUser request)
{ .... }

[Authenticate]
public object Put(UpdateAppUser request)
{ .... }
```

**2nd Update**

Here is the code from my AuthProvider:

```
public class BediCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
    {
        var authResponse = (AuthenticateResponse)base.Authenticate(authService, session, request);
        var user = (AppUser)authService.Request.Items["AppUser"];

        authResponse.Meta = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        authResponse.Meta.Add("TenantName", user.TenantName);
        authResponse.Meta.Add("ResetPwdRequired", user.MustChangePwd.ToString());
        authResponse.Meta.Add("IsLockedOut", user.IsLockedOut.ToString());
        authResponse.Meta.Add("Email", user.EmailAddress);
        authResponse.Meta.Add("DisplayName", user.DisplayName);
        authResponse.Meta.Add("RemoteIP", authService.Request.RemoteIp);

        return authResponse;
    }
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        AppUser user = null;
        using (var session = NhSessionFactories.OpenSession(TopinConstants.TopInDbFactory))
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var appUserRepo = new AccountManagementRepository(session);
                    user = appUserRepo.GetAppUser(userName);
                    transaction.Commit();
                    session.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error($"Error retrieving user {user} to authenticate. Error: {ex}");
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        if (user == null)
            throw HttpError.NotFound("User '{0}' not found. Please try again.".Fmt(userName));

        authService.Request.Items.Add("AppUser", user);
        var pwdMgr = new PwdManager();
        var hpwd = pwdMgr.GetHashedPassword(password, user.Salt);
        return hpwd == user.Password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack's [Request FilterAttribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) to authenticate a User has access to call a Service is the [[Authenticate]](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#the-authenticate-attribute) attribute. MVC's `[Authorize]` non-related attribute is for use in MVC only with no relationship to ServiceStack's Authentication.

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped my message! I corrected it by updating it.

Comment: @ThommyB ok but it's not possible to tell what the issue is from just that description, I'm assuming it's in your custom AuthProvider impl. Note you don't need to register `MemoryCacheClient`, it's already the default. Is the `UserAuthName` populated in the CacheClient after you authenticate?

Comment: I updated the message again and added the code for my AuthProvider. I registered MemoryCacheClient while searching for the problem because I thought it was missing....

Comment: @ThommyB Can you post the raw HTTP Request/Responses of both the successful authentication request and the failed Authentication request, you can use something like Fiddler to capture the raw HTTP Headers.

Comment: I guess I figured it out myself. I added the following to my AuthProvider: `public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService,
                IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens,
                Dictionary<string, string> authInfo) { return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo); } Seems to work now. Needs more testing. Does this make sense??

Comment: @ThommyB Overriding a method just to call its base method? That's not going to make any difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125951/discussion-between-thommyb-and-mythz).